# Smooth representatives for elements of $\pi_7(\text{exotic $S^7$})$

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M$ be $S^7$ with an exotic smooth structure. Since one can smoothen maps, there exist smooth maps $f:S^7\to M$ which are homotopic to the identity (relative to a base point, if you want).

> Can one make explicit one such map? Can such a map be an homeomorphism?

**Little addendum.**  The smooth homeomorphism constructed in Ryan's answer below is of course not a diffeomorphism.

> Does one have some control on the non-smooth locus of the inverse of smooth homeomorphims, or on the type of their non-smoothness there?

The inverse of Ryan's map is non-smooth only at the bad pole and I guess the initial map $h$ arises as the "conical differential" of the map there, so the singularity there is pretty bad. Maybe one can find other smooth homeomorphisms whose inverse has a larger non-smooth locus but with tamer non-smoothness there?

Answer (score 13):

Durán wrote down an explicit formula for such map in ["Pointed Wiedersehen Metrics on Exotic Spheres and Diffeomorphisms of $S^6$"](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1013163427655).  That is he wrote an explicit formula for an exotic diffeomorphism from $S^6$ to $S^6$ which is homotopic but not isotopic to the identity. This the produces an explicit homeomorphism from $S^7$ to an exotic sphere by glueing as described by Ryan in his [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/93488).

Geometric properties of that particular map were later studied by various people.
For example, it's written down explicitly on page 1 in ["Bootstrapping $Ad$-Equivariant Maps, Diffeomorphisms and Involutions"](https://mc.sbm.org.br/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/sites/9/2021/12/35-2.pdf)  by Durán and Rigas and Sperança (this link is freely accessible unlike the first one).

Answer (score 12):

I'll answer your question in two steps.  (1) You can make a degree one map $f : S^7 \to M$ a homeomorphism, and $C^\infty$-smooth on the complement of a point.

The idea is that you can construct $M$ as the union of two $D^7$'s

$$ M = D^7 \sqcup_{h} D^7$$

where the gluing map $h : S^6 \to S^6$ is some diffeomorphisms of $S^6$ that does not extend to a diffeomorphism of $D^7$.

To get a map $S^7 \to M$, just write $S^7 = D^7 \sqcup_{Id_{S^6}} D^7$, the map on the first $D^7$ factor $S^7 \to M$ is just the identity, and on the 2nd $D^7$ factor you're coning-off $h$, i.e. the extension of $h : S^6 \to S^6$ to a homeomorphism of $D^7$ is given by $\tilde h(tv) = th(v)$ provided $v \in S^6$ and $t \in [0,1]$.  This is usually called the Alexander trick, at least in the PL or topological categories.  This map is smooth everywhere except $0$ in the 2nd $D^7$ factor.

(2) To fix this argument and get a smooth homeomorphism, replace $\tilde h(tv) = th(v)$ with $\tilde h(tv)=\beta(t)h(v)$ where $\beta : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a $C^\infty$-smooth homeomorphism with all derivatives of $\beta$ zero at $0$, but otherwise $\beta'(t) > 0$ for $t \in (0,1]$.  You can cook up such functions readily using bump functions.

I think these arguments go back to Milnor's first papers on exotic smooth structures.  You can make every representative of $\pi_7 M$ smooth, by iteratively suspending the degree $k$ map $S^1 \to S^1$ and appropriately "dampening" at the cone-points, such as the above construction.

Comment: For some reason I expected this would not work, but surely it does. Thanks!